# Python Pandas dataframes merge update

Tags: python, pandas, merge, sql-update, insert-update

My problem is kind of a bit tricky (similar to sql merge/update), and not understanding how to fix: ( I am giving a small sample of the dataframes below)

I have two dataframes :

```
  dfOld 

     A   B  C  D  E
     x1  x2  g  h  r
     q1  q2  x  y  s
     t1  t2  h  j  u
     p1  p2  r  s  t
```

AND

```
 dfNew 

          A   B  C  D   E
          x1  x2  a  b  c
          s1  s2  p  q  r
          t1  t2  h  j  u
          q1  q2  x  y  z
```

We want to merge the dataframes with the following rule : ( we can think Col A & ColB as keys)

For any ColA & ColB combination if C/D/E are exact match then it takes value from any dataframe, however if any value has changed in Col C/D/E , it takes the value from new dataframe and if a new ColA/Col B combination is in DfNew then it takes those values and if the ColA/ColB combination does not exist in dfNew then it takes the value from dfOld:

***So my OutPut should be like:***

```
            A   B  C  D   E
            x1  x2  a  b  c
            q1  q2  x  y  z
            t1  t2  h  j  u
            p1  p2  r  s  t
            s1  s2  p  q  r
```

I was trying :

```
    mydfL = (df.merge(df1,indicator = True, how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both'])
    mydfR = (df1.merge(df,indicator = True, how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both'])


    dfO = pd.concat([mydfL,mydfR])

    dfO.drop("_merge", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

My output looks like: ( I kept the index for clarity)

```
            A   B  C  D  E
        0  x1  x2  a  b  c
        2  s1  s2  p  q  r
        3  q1  q2  x  y  z
        0  x1  x2  g  h  r
        2  q1  q2  x  y  s
        3  p1  p2  r  s  t
```

**However, this output does not serve my purpose**. First and foremost it does not include the totally identical row (between dfOld & dfnew) which consists of :

```
          t1  t2  h  j  u
```

and next it includes all the rows where for the ColA/Col x, y and q1, q2, where I just wanted the updated values in ColC/D/E in the new data frame ( dfNew). It includes data from both.

So can I get some help as to what am I missing and what may be a better and elegant way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) using A/B as temporary index:

```
out = (dfNew.set_index(['A', 'B'])
            .combine_first(dfOld.set_index(['A', 'B']))
            .reset_index()
      )
```

Comment: Wanted to ask you though @mozway, for very big dataframes, can we do a similar thing using vaex or dask or similar?

Comment: @Stan I don't know, you should ask with the proper tags ;)